# Kraken API for OHLC data to only append latest entries

Tags: python, kraken.com

So I'm running code on the Kraken API and I'm getting the data I want in the form of OHLC data of 718 rows and 8 columns. I want to get real time updates on this data so I figured I would use threading to run the code periodically every 5 seconds but all this is doing is printing the whole block of data again and again.

How do I only append data not present in the previous output. ie. the new entries every five seconds.

My code is below:

```
import krakenex
from pykrakenapi import KrakenAPI
import threading

api = krakenex.API()
api.load_key('/path/kraken.txt')
k = KrakenAPI(api)

ohlc, last = k.get_ohlc_data("BCHUSD")

def printit():
    threading.Timer(5.0,printit).start()
    print(ohlc)

printit()
```

Comment: has my answer helped you?

Comment: Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Kraken OHLC endpoint](https://www.kraken.com/features/api#get-ohlc-data) is designed for 9 different time intervals (1, 5, 15, 30, 60, 240, 1440, 10080, and 21600 minutes), of which 1 minute is the default interval. An issue with this is that you will not be able using this endpoint to obtain new data every 5 seconds, although every minute would work.
In this case you can use the `since` parameter for the OHLC endpoint, as follows, to get all instances after the last instance you found earlier.

```
import time
import krakenex
import pandas as pd
from pykrakenapi import KrakenAPI

api = krakenex.API()
k = KrakenAPI(api)

# Initial OHLC dataframe
df, last = k.get_ohlc_data("BCHUSD", ascending=True)

# Infinite loop for additional OHLC data
while True:
    # Wait 60 seconds
    time.sleep(60)

    # Get data and append to existing pandas dataframe
    ohlc, last = k.get_ohlc_data("BCHUSD", since=last + 60000, ascending=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, ohlc])

    print(f'1 new data point downloaded. Total: {len(df.index)} data points.')
```

If you *do* want to get OHLC data with 5-second intervals, you will have to construct this yourself from trades data obtained with the [Kraken Recent Trades endpoint](https://www.kraken.com/features/api#get-recent-trades).

```
import time
import krakenex
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pykrakenapi import KrakenAPI
from datetime import timedelta


def convert_to_ohlc(df, granularity):
    # Determine time frame of data
    since = df['time'].iloc[0] * 1000000000
    to =  df['time'].iloc[-1] * 1000000000

    # Create an initial data table with entries from start till end time, with steps of 5 seconds
    timestamps = pd.date_range(since, to, freq=str(granularity) + 's')

    # Initialise output dataframe
    output = pd.DataFrame(index=timestamps, columns=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])

    # Step through data in steps of 5 seconds
    df['dtime'] = df.index
    df = df.set_index('time')
    for i in range(0, len(output.index)):
        # Select the relevant datapoints for this step
        relevant_rows = df[
            (df['dtime'] >= output.index[i]) &
            (df['dtime'] < (output.index[i] +
                              timedelta(seconds=granularity)))
            ]

        # Convert data in time frame to OHLC data
        if len(relevant_rows) > 0 and not relevant_rows.empty:
            # open
            output.loc[output.index[i], 'open'] = relevant_rows['price'].iloc[0]
            # high
            output.loc[output.index[i], 'high'] = np.max(relevant_rows['price'])
            # low
            output.loc[output.index[i], 'low'] = np.min(relevant_rows['price'])
            # close
            output.loc[output.index[i], 'close'] = relevant_rows['price'].iloc[-1]
        else:
            for col in output.keys():
                output.loc[output.index[i], str(col)] = np.nan

    return output

api = krakenex.API()
k = KrakenAPI(api)

# Get trades data
df, last = k.get_recent_trades("BCHUSD", ascending=True)

# Convert data to OHLC data, steps of 5 seconds
df = convert_to_ohlc(df, 5)

# Infinite loop for additional OHLC data
while True:
    # Wait 60 seconds for new trades to happen
    time.sleep(60)

    # Get new trades data
    data, last = k.get_recent_trades("XBTUSD", since=last, ascending=True)

    # Convert data to OHLC data, steps of 5 seconds
    if not data.empty:
        data = convert_to_ohlc(data, 5)
        df = pd.concat([df, data])

        print(f'{len(data.index)} new data point{"s" if len(data.index) > 1 else ""} downloaded. Total: {len(df.index)} data points.')
    else:
        print("Could not find new trades. Retrying...")
```

You should realise that OHLC data is a summary of trades made in a certain time frame. Within 5 seconds, oftentimes no trades are made, meaning no OHLC data can be generated. Interpretability is another issue, as OHLC data on very few trades may have little meaning, especially when only one trade was made.